# No console window in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The console window in eclipse disappeared.

How can I open it? Its not possible to print `System.out.println()`.

[image: Here the picture]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check in this menu

**Windows > Show View > Console (Alt + Shift + Q, C)**

Answer (score 3):

Use shortcut:

```
Alt + Shift + Q, C
```

Answer (score 0):

The Console is one of many views you can configure in Eclipse.  To add a new view go to Window > Show View.